# Adding event to row of simple grid

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I created a grid using knockout simple grid.  How can I add a clickable button in each row so that every time I click the add button it will call a function.

```
 this.gridViewModel = new ko.simpleGrid.viewModel({
    data: this.items,
    columns: [
        { headerText: "Item Name", rowText: "name" },
        { headerText: "Sales Count", rowText: "sales" },
        { headerText: "Price", rowText: function (item) { return "$" + item.price.toFixed(2) } },
        { headerText: "Add", rowText: "Add"}
    ],
    pageSize: 4
});
```

Here is my jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/ramon26cruz/fNhKp/1/

Comment: You cannot do this without modifying the source of `ko.simpleGrid`. Use KoGrid https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/KoGrid istead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, nemesv is right, this is probably not meant for production use.

If you still wish to change it, you can overwrite the template it uses to render the grid(updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fNhKp/4/).

So first create a new template and specify the simpleGridTemplate binding:

```
<div class='liveExample'>     
    <div data-bind='simpleGrid: gridViewModel, simpleGridTemplate:"custom_grid_template"'> </div>      
</div>

    <script type="text/javascript" id="custom_grid_template">
    <table class="ko-grid" cellspacing="0">
                            <thead>
                                <tr data-bind="foreach: columns">
                                   <th data-bind="text: headerText"></th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody data-bind="foreach: itemsOnCurrentPage">
                               <tr data-bind="foreach: $parent.columns">
                                   <!--ko if: typeof rowText == 'object' && typeof rowText.action == 'function'-->
                                   <td><button data-bind="click:rowText.action($parent)">action</button></td>
                                   <!-- /ko -->
                                   <!--ko ifnot: typeof rowText == 'object' && typeof rowText.action == 'function'-->
                                   <td data-bind="text: typeof rowText == 'function' ? rowText($parent) : $parent[rowText] "></td>
                                   <!--/ko-->
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
    </script>
```

And then modify your js like this:

```
var PagedGridModel = function(items) {
    this.items = ko.observableArray(items);

    this.gridViewModel = new ko.simpleGrid.viewModel({
        data: this.items,
        columns: [
            { headerText: "Item Name", rowText: "name" },
            { headerText: "Sales Count", rowText: "sales" },
            { headerText: "Price", rowText: function (item) { return "$" + item.price.toFixed(2) } },
            { headerText: "Add", rowText: "Add"},
            { headerText: "Action", rowText: {action: function(item){
                return function(){
                    console.log(item)
                }
                }}}
        ],
        pageSize: 4
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery to add a click event:

```
 this.gridViewModel = new ko.simpleGrid.viewModel({
    data: this.items,
    columns: [
        { headerText: "Item Name", rowText: "name" },
        { headerText: "Sales Count", rowText: "sales" },
        { headerText: "Price", rowText: function (item) { return "$" + item.price.toFixed(2) }     },
        { headerText: "Add", rowText: "Add"}
    ],
    pageSize: 4
});
$('table.ko-grid tr td:last').live('click',function() {
    // Do something here...
});
```

Comment: This won't work. You cannot have html in the `rowText` property. Only property names of the item objects or a function returning string is permitted but it return value will be html encoded. http://jsfiddle.net/JJb2v/

Comment: You were right. I changed the method by binding the event on the table cell.

Comment: This would be additionally against the purpose of knockout ;-) knockout exactly trying to avoid using such jquery click event handler...